# python how to nicely align long text in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, alignment, indentation

Given a panda's dataframe (received from a database) I'm trying to output the result to the console in such was that it will be **complete** and **readable**.

The challenge I have is with respect to the long text in 2 columns:LPQ_REASON & LPQ_RESOLUTION. You will note from the output below (`print df`) that both LPQ columns are ended with 3 dots (`...`) so I can't read the text. This comes despite my initial settings of:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

so the result on the console looks like this:

```
       ID     DIS_CASE_ID                        CREATION_DATE  type_2                                  LPQ_REASON                                     LPQ_RESOLUTION   RESOLUTION_CODE
       0           727990         61180481 2017-01-05 13:47:05    7891  The LPQ we know is shorto add is 25% (h...  This Memo was issued with conjunction to our j...              3979
       1           727889         61180482 2017-01-05 13:51:09    7891  The LPQ he collide will increase 15% (h...  This Memo was issued on matching viloation for...              3979
```

An optimal solution I'm looking for (if doable) is to print the entire line such that:

```
           ID      DIS_CASE_ID                  CREATION_DATE  type_2                                  LPQ_REASON                                     LPQ_RESOLUTION     RESOLUTION_CODE
            0           727990   61180481 2017-01-05 13:47:05    7891   The LPQ we know is shorto add is 25% (here       This Memo was issued with conjunction to our               3979
                                                                        comes the rest of the sentence. it might be      analysis to foster a better bs when writing
                                                                        long, or not, it might be short or whatever)  

            1           727889   61180482 2017-01-05 13:51:09    7891  The LPQ he collide will increase 15% yes and  This Memo was issued on matching viloation for                 3979
                                                                       here I'm going to write the entire sentence    who cares on what violation. just issued. 
                                                                       as if I really remember what was written. ha
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as optimal as you want, but you can try the following:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth',100)
```

where 100 is the column width you can choose. but this will not create a multi-line cell but rather a very long column.

or:

not much elegant, but
you can try and use 'tabulate' library (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) which creates nice text tables like:

```
+--------+-------+
| item | qty |
+========+=======+
| spam | 42 |
+--------+-------+
| eggs | 451 |
+--------+-------+
| bacon | 0 |
+--------+-------+
```

with tabulate you can use the '\n' new-line character.
just iterate over your text cells and put an '\n' every X characters (lets say every 50 characters).

a simple code for that:

```
for i in range(len(data)): 
    data.at[i,'text'] = data.at[i,'text'][0:50] + '\n' + data.at[i,'text'][50:]
```

the above is limited to only one line break, but you can improve it to make multi breaks for a long text. and also doesn't take into consideration whether it breaks in a middle of a word.

!Make sure to do that on a copy of the data, because it changes your data. and if you'll try to print it with a regular 'print' then you will see the '\n' stuck inside the middle of the text!